# JQuery dynamic function hide element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form

```
   <div class="componenti_attive riquadro" style="display: block;">
<h2>LE COMPONENTI POSITIVE DEL TUO BILANCIO</h2>
<p class="title redd1 has-success" style="display: block;">Reddito mensile del primo componente
<input name="reddito1" type="text" class="form-control num positivi valid" placeholder="Redditi primo componente ..." data-validation="number" data-validation-error-msg="Inserisci solo numeri senza virgole e decimali!" data-validation-optional="true" style=""></p>

<div class="btnPrint indietro1"><h2 class="stamp printMe">INDIETRO</h2></div>
<div class="btnPrint avanti2 avant"><h2 class="stamp printMe">AVANTI</h2></div>
</div>
```

I have jquery Validator (the input object must be number)
In case of error must be appear a span object (class form-error):

```
<p class="title redd_altri1 has-error" style="display: block;">Indicare il totale degli altri redditi (es. pensioni, indennità, rendite, etc.)
<input name="altri_redditi" type="text" class="num positivi form-control error" placeholder="Inserisci qui il totale mensile degli altri redditi ..." data-validation="number" data-validation-error-msg="Inserisci solo numeri senza virgole e decimali!" data-validation-optional="true" style="border-color: red;"><span class="help-block form-error">Inserisci solo numeri senza virgole e decimali!</span></p>
```

I would like that, if this object is displayed so the div class avant is hide

```
<div class="btnPrint avanti2 avant"><h2 class="stamp printMe">AVANTI</h2></div>
```

I have this js

```
$form.on('change', '.num',  function ()
   {var $errori = $('.form-error').length;
if ($errori > 0)
    {$('.avant').hide();}
    else {$('.avant').show();}
            });
```

but it doesn't work!!

Comment: can you please add a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

This is just a suggestion,
 but if you want to make disappear the div avant if the number entered in the fields is incorrect, you can obtain the result even without plugin
you can use a regex.([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/zm5vx/))

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.avant').hide()
    var tot=/^[+-]?\d+(\.\d+)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?$/
    $('input').on('keyup',function(){
        var str = $(this).val();
        if(tot.test(str)) {
          $('.form-error').hide()
           }else{$('.form-error').show()}
           if($('.form-error').is(':visible')){
               $('.avant').hide()
               }else{
                $('.avant').show()   
                }
        })
})
</script>
```

not having your complete code I had to opt for this solution.
..ciao alla prossima.

Comment: `$(document).ready( function() {
 var ck_validate = /^$|^[0-9]{1,45}$/
 $('#bilancio_familiare').on('keyup', '.num', function ()
 {
  var valore = $('.num').val(),
  $errori = $('.form-error').length;
  if
  ((!ck_validate.test(valore))||($errori!=0))
  {$('.avant').hide();}
  else {$('.avant').show();}
  });
});`
It works! thanks for idea!!